# How to create multiple routes dynamically for same function and pass data which is fetched on the basis of Unique ID to single template in FLASK

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am a newbie to FLASK.

I am creating an e-commerce site in flask and I want to create multiple routes dynamically for same function and pass data which is fetched on the basis of Unique ID to single template in FLASK.

Let me explain it.

I have a table in DB as below:

| id | category | slug |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cat1 | slug1 |
| 2 | cat2 | slug2 |
| 3 | cat3 | slug3 |
| 4 | cat4 | slug4 |

my python code is:

```
for (data in db):
    @app.route('/data["slug"]')
    def product_display(data["id"]):
        id = data["id"]
        products = fetch_products(id)
        return render_template('products.html', products=products)
```

Please let me know if this code will work or not.
If no then what should be the logic?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your asking for how to use variables in routes?

```
@app.route('/<slug>')
def product_display(slug):
    category = Category.query.filter_by(slug=slug).first_or_404()
    products = Product.query.filter_by(category_id=category.id).all()
    return render_template('products.html', category=category, products=products
```

[Read up more on route variables in the docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules)

### Generating links to all categories

You comment mentions ' that variable should be coming from for loop of data fetched from DB' the best way I can parse that you want, say, a listing of all current categories (like a navigation bar in an online shop)

You might add a second route:

```
@app.route('/all-categories')
def all_categories():
    categories = Category.query.all()
    return render_template('all_categories.html', categories=categories)
```

Then in your `all_categories.html` you would 'build' the urls to the first route:

```
<ul>
{% for category in categories %}
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('product_display', slug=category.slug) }}">{{ category.slug }} (or title...)</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

So both routes work together to get that 'looped data' from the database

Comment: Yes I want to use variables in routes but that variable should be coming from for loop of data fetched from DB as mentioned in my question, please let me know if it is unclear

Comment: I think my update might address what you're trying to do.  If it's not-- can you explain what you're trying to do from a less technical perspective? (for example "I'm trying to show a user a list of categories they can click on to see all the associated products")

Comment: I wanted to loop around the decorator, app.route, and passing in respective slug or id so that I can fetch the products associated with passed in category id or slug but your first answer does the workaround for me as of now, thank you so much